# Getting errors while trying to run WebView application

Tags: android, webview

I am creating an application in which I have to use webView and display a HTML file saved in application in  assets folder. This is my mainActivity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


WebView browser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv1);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.htm");
    WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      setContentView(browser);

}
```

}

and this is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test Application" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

 </TextView>
<WebView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wv1"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

</WebView>
```

whin I am trying to run this application , it goes crash..[image: this is the LogCat of errors when i run the application]

can any one please help me to find out what is the mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call `setContentView(browser)` because `browser` is already a child of another view -- the `LinearLayout`.

If you don't need the other views, just change the layout xml file and remove them, leaving only the `WebView`. Otherwise, remove the `setContentView(browser)` line.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `setContentView()` twice and supplying the view that already has a parent. That is why it is giving you the error saying `call removeView() on the child's parent first`. So remove `setContentView(browser)`.

Your code should look like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv1);
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.htm");
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aniruddha for helping me to understand the actual meaning of error LogCat. and I didn't mistyped, I just saved my file as test.htm as you can save it in both way either .html or .htm.

Comment: Matiash answered the same 49 Min back. You should have voted up his answer instead of posting the same as your answer. That's the whole purpose of voting up a answer and thats how SO works.

Comment: @Devraj Just to make it clear, the double `setContentView()` is _not_ the actual cause of the exception. You can call it as many times as you like -- but _you cannot supply a view that already has a parent_. This would've worked if you had removed the WebView from its parent first (although it would've been a very roundabout way of solving this problem).